# BlackBerry - Custom Layout

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, layout

I am very much new to the Blacberry development environment. I am trying to make a simple calculator application. But when i implement buttons it is always displaying one below the another. I need to custom place the controls. Is there any way to make the layout custom so that i can place my controls as i wish.

Thanks in advance,
Rateesh

Answer (score 0):

You can try [How To - Create a rich UI layout with TableLayoutManager](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_rich_UI_layout_with_TableLayoutManager.html?nodeid=1906675&vernum=0)